# Contractable and Simply Connected Doubling Spaces Homeomorphic to Euclidean Space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, homeomorphism

Is there a characterization of all simply connected, contractable doubling metric spaces which are homeomorphic to a simply connected subset of Euclidean space?

Comment: Are you looking for a criterion or a classification?  In the latter case, what are we classifying them up to?  Isometry? quasi-Isometry? bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism?

Comment: Up to a snowflaking, like in Assouad's theorem.  Basically, I'm asking when a doubling space is simply connected and contractable...